# MySQL query to select on-air program from playlist schedule

Tags: php, sql, date, time

I am trying to write **ONE** SQL query, which gives always gives **three** rows of results. Database is as follows:

```
uid | program_date | program_time | program_name
------------------------------------------------ 
1   | 2012-04-16   | 21:00        | Some movie
2   | 2012-04-16   | 23:00        | Program end
3   | 2012-04-17   | 10:00        | Animation
4   | 2012-04-17   | 11:00        | Some other movie
5   | 2012-04-17   | 12:00        | Some show
```

All I need - always have three rows - what is on air now, next and upcomming. So if today is `2012-04-16 21:00` it should output `Some movie`, `Program end`, `Animation`.

At `2012-04-17 00:00` it should output `Program end`, `Animation`, `Some other movie`.

Problem is that I need to "navigate" back in one day if there is no records `WHERE program_date = date("Y-m-d") AND program_time <= date("H:i:s");`

There is another problem - database does not have Unix timestamp field, only `Uid`, `program_date` (date field) and `program_time` (time field) and `program_name`.

Also, there might be, that `Uid`'s are not inserted into table in sequence, as some program entry might be inserted in between into existing program schedule.

I am trying various approaches, but want to do everything in one SQL query, without looping in PHP.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

As TV-people count and show time in rather strange manner, MySQL function may be created to handle their non-human ;-) logic easier:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TV_DATE(d CHAR(10), t CHAR(5))
RETURNS CHAR(16) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT(d, IF (t < "06:00", "N", " "), t);
```

User-defined functions are declared per-database and this may be done just once. `DETERMINISTIC` tells that function always return the same result for the same input and internal MySQL optimizer may rely on that. `N` is just a letter which is larger (in string comparison) than whitespace. Consider it as mnemonics for *next* or *night*.

**note**: Hours should be always formatted with 2 digits!

Then using this function we may select what we need even simpler:

```
-- what is on air now
(SELECT `program_name`, TV_DATE(`program_date`, `program_time`) AS `tv_time`
 FROM `table` 
 WHERE (`tv_time` <= TV_DATE(date("Y-m-d"), date("H:i"))
 ORDER BY `tv_time` DESC 
 LIMIT 1)

  UNION

-- next and upcomming
(SELECT `program_name`, TV_DATE(`program_date`, `program_time`) AS `tv_time`
 FROM `table`
 WHERE (`tv_time` > TV_DATE(date("Y-m-d"), date("H:i"))
 ORDER BY `tv_time` ASC
 LIMIT 0, 2)
```

Keep in mind, that if all records in DB are in future you'll get only 2 of them.
The same for situation, when the next program is the last one in DB.

You may add different constant values into queries in order to distinguish those 2 situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work as expected.

First part of union select does not take correct record from the database example from my first post, when date is 2012-04-17 and time is 00:00. 

This query works if time is from 10:00  :(

Comment: Stupid me: sorting conditions for several fields should be written different way. Now it is working (I tested)

Comment: There are still some bugs. Could you help please once more?

Comment: I have no experience with Mysql user defined functions, but I tried to run that. Mysql now has a function somewhere in memory but I can't run main query, it gives error #1054 - Unknown column 'tv_time' in 'where clause'

Comment: Well, I substituted row 'WHERE (tv_time > TV_DATE("2012-04-19", "23:30:00")' with  'WHERE (TV_DATE(program_date, program_time) > TV_DATE("2012-04-19", "23:30:00"))', so at least it works, maybe not as fast as it could. Anyway, now I think I can manipulate with date in PHP, because if tonight it is already 2012-04-20 01:00, I have to run query as it is 2012-04-19 01:00 and after 06:00, as it is 2012-04-20. That is OK for me. I will give it a try on production tomorrow morning. Thank you for your help again! :)

Comment: Thanks kirilloid, I have put it online and watched for some time, not it works as it should. Great! :) Maladec.